# Anaconda2 installation errors/$PATH

Tags: python, anaconda

GOAL: Setup python to run using Anaconda2 environment

I updated the .bash_profile in my home folder and pointed to anaconda2 first.

export PATH="/Users/myname/anaconda2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

but when I echo $PATH at the terminal, I get back this: `/Users/myname/anaconda2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`

Where did all that extra stuff come from? It is not in my file.

Could this explain why my .py files are saying they can't find any of the installed anaconda2 modules like numpy and numba that I call from my scripts?

When I run "python /users/myname/desktop/stackoverflow.py" at the command line I get back these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/users/myname/desktop/stackoverflow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np   File "/Users/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs   File "/Users/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc   File "/Users/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *   File "/Users/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx   File "/Users/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import umath ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/umath.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret   Referenced from: /Users/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/umath.so Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in /Users/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/umath.so
```

Comment: Well, your main error seems to be `Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret`, did you check that?

Comment: @DevOps Thank you! That was indeed the issue. Did a bit of research and found that I needed to update from mac os 10.8.5 to something much newer. In my case, I went to High sierra and everything worked.

Comment: Oh nice, taking note of that! We both learned something :)